# react-navigation 6 swipe from top to bottom closes current stack screen android 9

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6, react-native-gesture-handler

I have upgraded from react-navigation 5 to 6:

```
-    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.10.6",
-    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.15",
-    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.6",
-    "@react-navigation/routers": "^5.6.0",
-    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.3",
-    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.10.3",

NEW DEPS:
+    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.7.0",
+    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.4",
+    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.3.0",
+    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
+    "@react-navigation/routers": "^6.1.3",
+    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.9",
```

After the upgrade I noticed that on Android 8 and 9 some stack screens have some strage feature of closing current screen with swipe from top to bottom.

Adding `gestureEnabled: false` as navigator or screen option doesn't seem to have any effect.

Screenshots with close on swipe top to bottom:

[image: first image when drag started]

[image: second drag image]

See attached video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xt08w7S-bFXcOMx01WAzHGwLvLLwAl7e/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the content of the stack screens that has issues.

Check if the view is using a `ScrollView` component.

If it is, try to **use the `ScrollView` from `react-native-gesture-handler`** library instead of react-native.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the root navigator had `gestureEnabled: true` and for some reason the nested stack navigators could not overwrite that value on Android 8 and 9.

I had to set that to `false` in the root stack navigator to make it work for nested navigators too.

```
  screenOptions={{
    gestureEnabled: false
  }}
```

Note: there are multiple issues reported in github related to how that property works for Android. Some people applied as an workaround a huge swipe threshold.